# Opposite of "holistic" for an operator

Tags: terminology, order-theory

I am dealing with *preference relations*, i.e., strict partial orders on a given domain of objects. For example, if $R$ is a preference relation, the preference $a R b$ indicates that $a$ is better than $b$.

Such relations can be "combined" via some operators in order to produce new relations. So, for instance, one could combine two preference relations $R_1$ and $R_2$ with a binary operator $\circ$ to obtain a new preference relation $R_{12}=R_1\circ R_2$.

Now, for some of these operators, whether $a R_{12} b$ holds only depends on whether $a R_1 b$ and $a R_2 b$ hold; in other words, the combined preference regarding $a$ and $b$ is independent of the preferences regarding the other objects in the domain. For example, I could invent an operator $\land$ such that $a (R_1\land R_2) b$ holds if and only if both $a R_1 b$ and $a R_2 b$ hold (thus I don't need to check anything else to conclude whether $a (R_1\land R_2) b$ holds).

My question: what is the right adjective to characterize such an operator?

Some proposals that came to mind are *local* and *point-wise* (or *object-wise*, or even *atomic* or *atomistic*), but I was hoping that there could be a more standard term used in the literature.

The opposite of this seems rather clear: a *holistic* operator, i.e., one that needs to look at the whole input relations in order to determine whether $a R_{12} b$ holds. A holistic operator is, e.g., one for which $R_1 \circ R_2$ is $R_1$ if $R_1\neq\emptyset$ and $R_2$ otherwise; here whether $a (R_1 \circ R_2) b$ holds does not only depend on whether $a R_1 b$ and $a R_2 b$ hold, but also on whether there are entries (possibly different from $a R_1 b$ in $R_1$).

Comment: It somehow reminds me of "separation of variables", so $\land$ could be called a *separable* operator. That's not a standard literature term, though.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks. While I'm waiting for other possible suggestions, do you agree that "holistic" is the right term for the non-"separable" operators?